# Byte Order Conversion in Java for Network and Host order

Tags: java, encoding, network-programming, endianness

The topic is rather simple, but I might have confused myself a bit here. Network byte order is Big-Endian. Java by default uses Big-endian as well (as in the case of class files). My windows machine uses Intel processors, which are Little-Endian and windows itself also uses Little-Endian. So, if I uses a `java.nio.ByteBuffer.allocateDirect()`, then the default Endianness is Little-Endian (*because of the OS and/or the processor*), however, if I want to send this data on network, on reading data from  `ByteBuffer`, do I need to use `ByteBuffer.order(ByteOrder.BIG_ENDIAN)`? Additionally, Do i have to do the reverse while reading the data from a `Channel` to a `ByteBuffer`? I almost ignored it when using `java.io` package

Another part of the question is also related to working on the machine itself.

1. Should I always be aware of the Endianness of my host machine? So, whatever local data storage format is used, its fine within this machine's environment, however, convert the data to BIG_ENDIAN when sending to network.
2. In terms of Endianness, for default file formats, say on windows, its always Little-Endian. However, now using the same file on a MAC or a Linux with Big-Endian, should I save it with a Byte-order-Marking (BOM)?

Comment: Your last question doesn't make sense. Character sets don't have anything to do with endian-ness.

Comment: Edited to remove the UTF-8 confusion. Can you pls. also see my comments to @TwoThe. Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> The topic is rather simple, but I might have confused myself a bit here. Network byte order is Big-Endian. Java by default uses Big-endian as well (as in the case of class files).

In the case of class files, DataOutputStream, DataInputStream, ObjectInputStream, ObjectOutputStream, and java.nio.*, and I've probably left something out.

> If I uses a java.nio.ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(), then the default Endianness is Little-Endian (because of the OS and/or the processor)

No. 'The order of a newly created ByteBuffer is always big-endian'. See the Javadoc.

> If I want to send this data on network, on reading data from ByteBuffer, do I need to use ByteBuffer.order(ByteOrder.BIG_ENDIAN)?

It already is.

> Additionally, Do i have to do the reverse while reading the data from a Channel to a ByteBuffer?

It already is.

> I almost ignored it when using java.io package

DataInputStream and DataOutputStream use big-endian. See the Javadoc.

> Should I always be aware of the Endianness of my host machine?

Not in Java.

> So, whatever local data storage format is used, its fine within this machine's environment, however, convert the data to BIG_ENDIAN when sending to network.

That already happens by default.

> In terms of Endianness, for default file formats, say on windows, its always Little-Endian.

No it isn't. See above.

> However, now using the same file on a MAC or a Linux with Big-Endian, should I save it with a Byte-order-Marking (BOM)?

See above. Not necessary.

Comment: Thanks for you answers. I think I can completely ignore about Endianness in java since its always is BIG_ENDIAN by default. Somewhere I read that for latency sensitive applications, awareness of Endianness is advantageous if not critical to save a swap. However, looks like I almost dont have to worry about it. Thanks again.

Comment: Well obviously Java has to use the platform endian-ness internally when push comes to shove, e.g. adding registers together, but there's no way to observe that from within a Java program.

Answer (score -2):

You need to always send the same Endian style. Which one you choose should be based on how fast it can be processed on the host. If your code is i.E. primarily used on x86 based machines, it is recommended to use little Endian all over the place. Internally the JVM will do the same (on this OS).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. So, JVM, besides class writing, will use the same Endianness as the default OS, so I now understand that network byte order should always be first converted to Big-Endian on send/receive irrespective. My confusion still remains about, if java.net and/or java.io and/or java.nio API does the hton(host to network) and ntoh(network to host) by itself? Another part of the question remains, 'what if I copy a windows file (little endian) to Apple MAC (big-endian) using a USB drive?' Where do I determine in file/header about its endiannes?

Comment: Another question that I wanted to ask you is: If the default JVM is using Little-Endian (same as the host), then do I have to reverse the order of my InputStream read() OR the ByteBuffer reading to Big-Endian? In my experience, I havent had any instances where I had to do this because I am always in Windows world, so assuming that java is taking care of it on its own. Pls. comment.

Comment: Thoroughly misleading answer. Java hides all this from you. You don't have to do anything about it whatsoever. -1

Comment: @EJP, I have been checking on this as well and it your answers above look more in line with java doc.